# DisplayName is disappeared when Runtime is set

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, manifest, office-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I have a PowerPoint Add-in. There is a manifest file.
It contains a tag

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Office App"/>
```

The taskpane has a header as expected:

[image]

Everything works fine until I add

```
<Runtimes>
    <Runtime resid="Defaults.Url" lifetime="long" />
</Runtimes>
```

With this tag, my taskpane does not contain the header anymore:

[image]

This tag is required, because Enable and Disable Add-in Commands programmatically possible only with shared runtime.

Manifest file checked, it does not contain errors.

Any idea why the label does not appear with shared runtime?

Comment: Which platform are you testing on? Windows desktop? Mac desktop, Office online?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'd suggest posting that to the OfficeJS repo as an issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues.

Comment: @RickKirkham Hi. It's online.